# How to ignore - in numbers in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an app which finds users based on their contact lists and some phones storing phone numbers in contacts like `0811-111-1111` so there are dashes in between numbers while in my database numbers are integer like `08111111111` this will prevent my search function to work correctly and I want to ignore all those dashed before match incoming request against my database.

Question is how?

#### Code

```
public function show(Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();
  
    $nums = []; // get list of all numbers from user (some are include dashes)
    foreach($request->phones as $phone) {
        foreach($phone['_objectInstance']['phoneNumbers'] as $number) {
                $nums[] = $number['value'];
        }
    }

    // check it against my database
    $contacts = User::whereIn('phone', $nums)->get();

    // return the results
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $contacts,
        'message' => 'Contacts retrieved successfully.'
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use str_replace function to replace '-' by ''.

```
foreach($request->phones as $phone) {
        foreach($phone['_objectInstance']['phoneNumbers'] as $number) {
                $nums[] = str_replace('-','',$number['value']);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be

```
$nums = "'". implode("','",$nums) ."'";
$contacts = User::whereRaw(DB::raw("replace(phone,'-','') in ({$nums})"))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PCRE (using `preg_replace`) to remove all charachter except numbers:

```
foreach($request->phones as $phone) {
        foreach($phone['_objectInstance']['phoneNumbers'] as $number) {
                $nums[] = preg_replace('/[^0123456789]/', '', $number['value']);
    //                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // It will replace all character except for number to ''
    // Explanation:
    // preg_replace( __REGEX__, __REPLACEMENT__, __INPUT__): string
    // __REGEX__ : Using /[^0123456789]/ which mean all from these charset
    // (inside [] bracket) and except for (using `^` after `[`) 0123456789,
    // these can be simplified to /[^\d]/, where \d is for `digits`
    // __REPLACEMENT__ : Using '' because you need to remove it
    // __INPUT_ : your phone number input


        }
    }
```

Hope this will answer your questing, sorry for my bad explanation